# Как создать ожидающий поток в Java?

Tags: java, clips

Пишу экспертную систему с использованием CLIPS. Реализовав интерфейс Router я смогу перенаправить ввод и вывод CLIPS в Java. Осталась проблема связи ввода с GUI. Мне необходимо создать поток, который будет ждать пока не будет нажата кнопка и поток завершится. Т.е. при нажатии кнопки я буду изменять значение переменной которая будет передана в CLIPS  и завершать поток, чтобы переменная попала в CLIPS.

Comment: gui то у вас какой ?

Comment: при такой постановке вопроса совсем необязательно, чтобы поток чего-то ждал, можно по нажатию на кнопку и создавать поток и говорить ему, что делать